# WORDPRESS UPDATE DB method not get called

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, plugins

I am making a wordpress plugin, where I have functions in the main php file:

```
<?php
include_once "define.php";
include_once 'includes/form_processor.php';
include_once 'includes/email_subscriber.php';
include_once 'includes/options_page.php';
include_once 'includes/widget.php';

//register the plugin installation methods
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'install_simple_subscriber_plugin');
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'uninstall_simple_subscriber_plugin');

//register the plugin url
wp_enqueue_style('simple-email-subscriber-css', plugins_url('/simple_email_subscriber/stylesheets/style.css'));

function install_simple_subscriber_plugin(){
  add_action('plugins_loaded', 'setup_plugin_actions');
  email_subscriber::install_database();
  email_subscriber::update_database();
}


function setup_plugin_actions(){
  if(has_action('publish_post')){
   $simple_email_subscriber = new email_subscriber();
    //add action listener to post publication
    add_action('publish_post', array($simple_email_subscriber, 'on_publish_post'));
    add_action('publish__future_post', array($simple_email_subscriber, 'on_publish_post'));
  }

  //add the admin menu pages
  $options_page = new options_page();
}

function uninstall_simple_subscriber_plugin(){
  remove_action('plugins_loaded', 'setup_plugin_actions');
}
?>
```

AND in my custom class I have:

```
<?php
class email_subscriber{
  /*
   * Plugin Core Methods
   * */
  static function install_database() {
    //define create table query
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".SIMPLE_EMAIL_SUBSCRIBER_DB_NAME."(
      id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      subscribe_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      email VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL,
      UNIQUE KEY id (id)
    );";

    //update db and make it auto adjust
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    dbDelta($sql);
  }

  //HERE IS THE NEW BITS ADDED TO THE EXISTING PLUGIN THAT'S NOT GET CALLED
  static function update_database(){
    $sql=
      "DELIMITER $$
      CREATE PROCEDURE Alter_Table()
      BEGIN
        DECLARE _count INT;
          SET _count = (  SELECT COUNT(*) 
                      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                      WHERE   TABLE_NAME = 'email_subscription' AND 
                              COLUMN_NAME = 'subscribe_all');
      IF _count = 0 THEN
          ALTER TABLE ".SIMPLE_EMAIL_SUBSCRIBER_DB_NAME."
              ADD COLUMN subscribe_all TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 1,
              ADD COLUMN subscribe_category varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL;
      END IF;
  END $$
  DELIMITER ;
  CALL Alter_Table();
  DROP PROCEDURE Alter_Table;
  ";
//update db and make it auto adjust
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
dbDelta($sql);

//add the options for db defination
add_option("ses_db_version", SES_PLUGIN_VERSION);
  }


.................and other codes
}
```

The update_database() method is the new method I added in, that's trying to update the database for extra functions. but it's never get run when the plugin activates.

Comment: no error at all.....that's why I am so frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to execute that query.

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query($sql);
```

`dbDelta` is used to create new tables or update existing ones to conform to an updated scheme. Simply put, it accepts a `CREATE TABLE` query and transforms it into an `ALTER TABLE` query if necessary. [The Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins#Creating_or_Updating_the_Table) says:

> The dbDelta function examines the current table structure, compares it
>   to the desired table structure, and either adds or modifies the table
>   as necessary, so it can be very handy for updates [...] Note that the
>   dbDelta function is rather picky, however.

Comment: Hey. nice suggestion, I tried your method, in facted, I even tried:$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare(sql)); as well. non of them work. The plugin starts fine with no error, but it seems the sql is just never get run.(if I run it through mysql command line it works, so the syntax is correct)

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that `update_database()` is being called? You could try adding an `echo` or `die` inside the method to see if it actually shows up.

Comment: HI: super idea. I added a die in the beginning of the update_datebase() method, and trying to active my plugin: Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error.. So it is getting called. but just not showing any error nor working.

Comment: If I change my sql query to a straight alter table, it will run ok and the DB get modified. but this procesure seems not working. although it doesn't give me any error, and it runs fine from mysql command line.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas here. Does the database account which WordPress uses to login have the proper permissions to create and execute procedures?